# Libre Office showing strange characters

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. In my system I have `Libre Office` installed. I don't use libre office so frequently. I had used it around 20-25 days before, at that time it was okay. But when I used that to make one document I saw there are some strange characters are showing after every paragraph and after every words it is showing one dot.

For better understand I have uploaded the screenshot. There you can see the strange characters with dots. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. I have tried to on off the Libre Office many times and my system restart but its not working.
The image can be seen [here](http://i40.tinypic.com/96je5w.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are formatting (or 'non-printing') characters.

To disable them, go to the **View** menu, and disable (uncheck) the "Nonprinting characters" option.

[image]